# How to create a custom Record with sample data in a jOOQ's MockDataProvider?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

I am trying to implement a unit test using [jOOQ's mocking tools](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/) but failing to understang how to create custom records and put some data on them.

This is my `MockDataProvider`:

```
private static class MyProvider implements MockDataProvider {
    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        log.trace("SQL = {}", ctx.sql());

        DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MARIADB);
        MockResult[] mockResults = new MockResult[1];

        if (ctx.sql().startsWith("select `gc`.`article`.`id`, `gc`.`familia`.`iva` from")) {
            Record2<Integer, Byte> record2 = create.newRecord(ARTICLE.ID, FAMILIA.IVA);
            log.debug("record2 = " + record2);
            log.debug("record2.value1()={}" + record2.value1());
            Record2<Integer, Byte> values = record2.values(1, (byte) 10);
            log.debug("record2.value1()={}" + record2.value1());
            log.debug("values = " + values);
            mockResults[0] = new MockResult(record2);
        }
        return mockResults;
    }
}
```

And this is the output of the different log statements:

```
12:21:05.670 [main] DEBUG net.sargue.gc.test.TestArticleDAO - record2 = +------+------+
|    id|   iva|
+------+------+
|{null}|{null}|
+------+------+
12:21:05.671 [main] DEBUG net.sargue.gc.test.TestArticleDAO - record2.value1()={}null
12:21:05.671 [main] DEBUG net.sargue.gc.test.TestArticleDAO - record2.value1()={}null
12:21:05.671 [main] DEBUG net.sargue.gc.test.TestArticleDAO - values = null
```

So it seems to ignore setting values (third log output) and fully returns null from that method. Not sure if it's a bug or I am doing something wrong.

By the way, setting values one by one seems to work ok.

```
record2.value1(1)
```

Which it's what I am doing now as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an unfortunate bug [#5042](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5042), which was fixed in jOOQ 3.7.3 (and will be fixed in 3.6.5 and 3.5.5).

That `values()` method was only added the API, not to the implementation, [which is empty](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.7.2/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/RecordImpl.java#L503) ;)

If upgrading is not yet a possibility, you can still use individual setters (as you did) or the unsafe [`Record.from()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from-java.lang.Object-) to which you can pass an array:

```
// Using from()
record2.from(new Object[] { 1, (byte) 10 });

// Or simpler, using fromArray()
record2.fromArray(1, (byte) 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, missed the update. Tested with 3.7.3 and it works perfectly.